Kubernetes Service external ip address is stuck at <pending>
I am practicing on Kubernetes, I made 1 frontend and 1 backend services.
First service is mongodb-service, this is an internal service.
Second service is mongo-express-service, this is an external service.
When I run kubectl get svc, I get:
NAME                    TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          68m
mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.111.8.103     <pending>     8081:30000/TCP   56m
mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.100.153.155   <none>        27017/TCP        56m


When I try to access the 30000 port through browser using my.ec2.public.ip:30000 I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED and sometimes it keeps loading.
Here is my mongo-express.yml:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mongo-express
        image: mongo-express
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key: mongodb-root-username
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
          valueFrom: 
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-secret
              key:  mongodb-root-password
        - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
          valueFrom: 
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb-configmap
              key: database_url

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 8081
    targetPort: 8081
    nodePort: 30000


# minikube service mongo-express-service

Project source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX4AaiRsQaA
How can I debug this?
What have I tried to fix this?
1- Restart my EC2 Instance - Didn't work
2- Change inbound rules in security groups to all TCP and All Traffic - Didn't work
3- I tried using minikube tunnel, kept it running and tried to access the external IP that appeard - Didn't work
4- Deleted all services and did kubectl apply -f again - Didn't work.

Your cluster needs a controller of some sort that's able to provide the external load balancer and IP address.  If you're running this on AWS, the EKS hosted Kubernetes setup can do this automatically.

Since you are using a LoadBalancer type service, the pending status for the EXTERNAL-IP  indicates that Kubernetes is unable to provision an external IP  address for your svc.
